# VBA EXCEL CODE: Current Stock Price

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to coding and programing and would appreciate any suggestions you can give me in creating my first real code.

What I want it to do is ask the user what the Ticker Name is of the stock and once that is input, a message box should display the current price of the stock.

I know the formula to extract the current stock price.
For Example: to find the current value of Netflix all you have to do in a spreadsheet is put "NFLX" in cell(A1) and in cell(A2) put the following formula:
`=NUMBERVALUE(WEBSERVICE("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="&A1&"&f=l1"))`

Yesterday while learning how to define variables in VBA I was trying to experiment with this concept and came up with the following code which obviously doesn't work:-

```
Sub Declaring_Variables()

    Dim TickerName As String

    TickerName = InputBox("Ticker Symbol")

    Dim CurrentPrice As Integer

    CurrentPrice = Formula ="=NUMBERVALUE(WEBSERVICE("finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="&TickerName&"&f=l1"))

    MsgBox (CurrentPrice)
End Sub
```

I am sure the problem is with the way I have declared the formula for CurrentPrice. I would really appreciate if you can teach me how to use normal formulas which we use on spreadsheet in VBA. I think this will be a good example for me to get better as it covers a very important concept.

Thank you for your time.

Regards,
InWoods

Comment: an obvious issue is that you misspelled `WEBSERVIC`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks edited that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Declaring_Variables()

    Dim TickerName As String

    TickerName = InputBox("Ticker Symbol")

    Dim CurrentPrice As String

    CurrentPrice = Application.WebService("finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & TickerName & "&f=l1")

    MsgBox "Text Format: " & CurrentPrice & Chr(10) & _
        "Number Format: " & Application.NumberValue(CurrentPrice)
End Sub
```